# Is it necessary that $\sum{a_{2^k}}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence of reals and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =0 $. 
> Suppose that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: M|{a_n} - a_{n+1}| \geq |a_{n+2} -a_{n+1}| $.
> Is it necessary that $\sum{a_{2^k}}$ converges?

I know that if we don't assume the existence of such $M$, then the answer is no (e.g $\forall \space n \in \mathbb{N}$  $a_n = \frac{1}{k}$ if $n = 2^k$ for some natural $k$ and else $a_n = 0$). However I struggle to either prove or find a counter-example for the mentioned argument.

I would like to have some guidance, thanks

Comment: what can you say about $a_n - a_{n+1}$ from $a_0 - a_1$?

Comment: What would your answer be to whether it is necessary that $\sum a_n$ converges?  Could you adapt that to $\sum{a_{2^k}}$?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I can see that for each $n \in \mathbb{N} \space: |a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq M^{n}|a_1-a_0|$

Comment: Did the question put any restriction on $M$ such as $M < 1$? If not, then choosing $M=1$ will allow a counterexample

Comment: @Henry No, but just after reading your answer, if we assume this or something that implies this, then the series converges, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes as you and @julio_es_sui_glace have spotted, requiring $M<1$ would make the series $\sum a_n$ absolutely convergent by comparison to a geometric series, and so the sum of a selection of the terms also absolutely convergent

Comment: @Henry In the case where $M < 1$, I struggle to see how we can "bound" $(a_n)$ by a geometric series. As far as I can see, we can bound $(|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|)$ this way.

Comment: @X4J: you may be right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something like $a_{2^k} = \frac{1}{k}$
then letting $n=2^k$ i.e. $k=\log_2(n)$ you get $a_n=\frac1{\log_2(n)}$
and you can use this for all positive $n$.

$a_n=\dfrac1{\log_2(n)}$ now satisfies your requirements for a counterexample:

- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n =0$
- using $M=1$ you have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N^+}: |{a_n} - a_{n+1}| \gt |a_{n+2} -a_{n+1}|$
- $\sum{a_{2^n}} =\sum\frac1{\log_2(2^n)} = \sum\frac1{n}$ which diverges to $+\infty$