# Does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of reals and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$. 
> Suppose that there exists $M \in (0, 1)$  s.t for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \leq M|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$. 
> Does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely?

This questions follows my previous one: [Is it necessary that $\sum{a_{2^k}}$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761590/is-it-necessary-that-suma-2k-converges).

I struggle to either prove or find a counter-example to this argument and I'm not sure how to proceed (I could only find a counter-example for the case where $M=1$).

I'd like to have some insights\guidance, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For $1 \le n < m$ is
$$
 |a_n - a_m| \le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} |a_{k+1} - a_k|
\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}  M^{k-1} |a_2-a_1| \le \frac{M^{n-1}}{1-M}|a_2-a_1| \, .
$$
It is given that $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m = 0$, therefore we can take the limit $m \to \infty$ and conclude that
$$
 |a_n| \le \frac{M^{n-1}}{1-M}|a_2-a_1| 
$$
for all $n$. It follows that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, by comparison with the geometric series. One also gets the estimate
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| \le \frac{|a_2-a_1|}{(1-M)^2} \, .
$$