# T\F: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}$ converges, does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_k}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a sequence of reals and $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 $.
>
> Assume that for each $n \in \mathbb{N} : |a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$.
>
>  If $(n_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ s.t $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}$ converges, does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_k}$ converge absolutely?

I asked this question as I'm curious to understand the analogous for derivative in discrete cases. 
If we instead assume $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} : |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ and the argument holds, I would expect the first argument to hold too as the "change" seems to be minor (this is only how I approached it intuitively).

I tried to use the idea of the proof presented as an answer to my previous question:

[Does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763306/does-it-imply-that-sum-n-1-inftya-n-converges-absolutely)

However my struggle is at the part where we want to bound $|a_n - a_m|$ without relying on the value of $m$ which may change (at the presented proof we use the limit in order to bound it, which, I guess, is not the case here).

I'd hope to get some ideas how to approach it, thanks.

Comment: What happens if $a_n = 1/\log(n)$?

Comment: @ncmathsadist It does not seem to verify $|a_n - a_{n+1}| \leq 1/n^2$, its more $|a_n - a_{n+1}| \ \sim 1/(n \ln^2(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sum converges absolutely.

Note that $|a_n - a_{N + 1}| \leq \sum\limits_{i = n}^N |a_i - a_{i + 1}| \leq \sum\limits_{i = n}^N \frac{1}{i^2} \leq \int\limits_{i = n - 1}^{N - 1} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \frac{1}{N - 1} - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $1 < n \leq N$.

Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ gives us that $|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n - 1}$.

Now take $j$ such that for all $k \geq j$, $n_j \geq 2$. Then $\sum\limits_{i = j}^\infty |a_{n_i}| \leq \sum\limits_{i = j}^\infty \frac{1}{n_i - 1} \leq 2 \sum\limits_{i = j}^\infty \frac{1}{n_i}$, which converges.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have $|a_k - a_{k+1} | \leq 1/n^2$, with $n < m $ you get
$$|a_{n} - a_{m}| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq  \int_{n-1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{t^2} dt  =  \frac{1}{n-1}- \frac{1}{m-1} .$$

We know that $a_n \to 0$, so by taking $m \to \infty$ in the previous inequality, we get $|a_n| = |a_n - a_\infty| \leq \frac{1}{n-1} \sim 1/n$

Now we just have to remark that $|a_{n_k}| \sim 1/n_k$ since $n_k \to \infty$, and this is the term of a convergent positive series, which gives the A-C.